# PL/pgSQL вернуть свою строку

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Есть процедура

какая-то логика бегает по LOOP и формирует строки

могу ли я вернуть еще одну строку

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_all_foo2 (
  a timestamp = '2016-05-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone,
  aa timestamp = '2016-05-22 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone
)
RETURNS SETOF public.composite_type AS
$body$
DECLARE    
    r composite_type;
    f composite_type;
    tss timestamp;
    tse timestamp;
    tseb timestamp;
    tss2 timestamp;
    tse2 timestamp;    
    i integer = 0;

BEGIN
    FOR r IN
        SELECT entered + duration * interval '1 second' as ended, *, null FROM public.status_changes WHERE  entered > a and entered < aa
    LOOP
      if (r.status = 'away')    then 
            tss = r.entered;
                tse = r.ended;
                tss2 = r.entered;
                tse2 = r.ended;
        -- здесь возможна обработка данных
              FOR f IN
                    SELECT entered + duration * interval '1 second' as ended, *, null FROM public.status_changes WHERE  entered >= r.entered and 
                    entered + duration * interval '1 second' <= r.entered + r.duration * interval '1 second'
                LOOP


                  if (f.entered = tss and f.ended <= tse )
                      then
                          i = i + 1;
                          tss = f.ended;

                        end if;
                   r.entered = tss;

                     if (f.ended < tse)
                     then 
                      r.ended = f.entered;
                     end if;                  

                     if (f.entered > tss2 and f.ended <= tse2 and tss != f.ended and f.ended > tss)
                     then 
                        r.entered = f.ended;
                        r.ended = f.ended + f.duration * interval '1 second';

                        RETURN NEXT ('1 var', '2 var'); ---ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ХОЧУ СФОРМИРОВАТЬ СВОЮ СТРОКУ ЧТО ДОБАВИТСЯ К РЕЗУЛЬТАТУ

                     end if;
                     RAISE NOTICE '#% % ######### %     %      %',i, tss, tse, tss2, tse2;


                   r.t_dur = r.ended - r.entered;   
                     if (r.t_dur = '00:00:00')
                      then
                           r.t_dur = r.duration * interval '1 second';                         
                        end if;

                END LOOP;

        END IF;

         RETURN NEXT r;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100 ROWS 1000;
```

т.е. если это делать через next то вернется одна строка, а мне искусственно нужно добавить строку со своими данными

Comment: Получающий строку же ожидает получить одну. А следующую он ожидает получить при следующем вызове. Значит надо при первом обращении запомнить, что мы хотим вернуть свою строку и при следующем вызове _вместо_ всей этой логики ее вернуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно и самому строку сформировать

```
              RETURN NEXT  ( f.ended , tseb, 
                                    r.login,
                                    r.status,
                                    r.reason,
                                    r.duration,
                                    r.t_dur
                                    );
```