# Postgres хранимая процедура не понимает timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Возвращаю строку

```
                 if (f.entered > tss2 and f.ended <= tse2 and tss != f.ended and f.ended > tss)
                 then 

                    tseb =   (f.ended + f.duration * interval '1 second')::timestamp(0);           
                    RETURN NEXT  ( f.ended , tseb, 
                                    r.login,
                                    r.status,
                                    r.reason,
                                    r.duration,
                                    r.t_dur
                                    );                    
                 end if;
```

получаю

> ERROR:  returned record type does not match expected record type
>   DETAIL:  Returned type timestamp without time zone does not match
>   expected type timestamp(6) without time zone in column 2. CONTEXT: 
>   PL/pgSQL function get_all_foo2(timestamp without time zone,timestamp
>   without time zone) line 47 at RETURN NEXT

при этом ended - timestamp,  duration  - integer

не могу понять как привести к валидному типу

композитный тип

```
CREATE TYPE public.composite_type AS (
  ended TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  entered TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  login VARCHAR(100),
  status VARCHAR(100),
  reason VARCHAR(100),
  duration INTEGER,
  t_dur TIME(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE
);

tseb =   to_timestamp(f.ended + f.duration * interval '1 second', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone;
```

тоже не проходит

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT to_timestamp(f.ended + f.duration * interval '1 second', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_all_foo2(timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone) line 45 at assignment

а значение валидное 2016-05-21 12:17:00

Comment: Сократите пример до минимально-валидного

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566479/pl-pgsql-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83?noredirect=1#comment740826_566479

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который просил:

```
drop type fnsomefunc_type cascade;
create type fnsomefunc_type as (
    started TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    ended TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnsomefunc()
    RETURNS fnsomefunc_type AS
$$
DECLARE
    res timestamp;
BEGIN
    res = (now()::timestamp + 10 * interval '1 second');
    RETURN (res, now()::timestamp);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

> melkij=# select fnsomefunc();
>   ERROR:  returned record type does not match expected record type
>   DETAIL:  Returned type timestamp without time zone does not match expected type timestamp(6) without time zone in column 1.
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fnsomefunc() while casting return value to function's return type

Похоже на наблюдаемую ошибку? Вроде бы похоже. Воспользуемся явным приведением типов:

```
res = (now()::timestamp + 10 * interval '1 second');
RETURN (res::timestamp(6), now()::timestamp);
```

> melkij=# select fnsomefunc();
>   ("2016-09-15 12:18:46.598622","2016-09-15 12:18:36.598622")

Да, timestamp и timestamp(6) - рассматриваются как разные типы данных.

Comment: действительно                 tseb =    f.ended + f.duration * interval '1 second'; 
                             
                        RETURN NEXT ( f.ended , tseb::timestamp(0), r.login, r.status, r.reason, r.duration, r.t_dur );